# Elasticsearch RabbitMQ river

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq

I'm currently adding document changes through rabbitmq to elasticsearch via the bulk api (which is working like a charm) and I was wondering if there was any mechanism to send a message to another rabbitmq queue when that happens. I want to do stuff to the documents after the changes are applied in elasticsearch.

Is this possible at all? One solution might be is that I add a queue in between on which a worker listens that adds it to the elasticsearch queue and to the new changes queue but it sounds kind of tacky...

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be:

> when I ack a message in rabbit, can it put the message into a
>   different queue?

The answer is no.

I suggest that after your code that inserts into elasticsearch then created a new message and puts it in a new rabbit queue, then it acks the old message.